# AVPlayer : difference between observedBitrate and indicatedBitrate

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayeritem

I'm using `AVPlayer` to read HLS streams.

During playback, I need to get bitrate from `AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent` object. In this object, I can get the `observedBitrate` or the `indicatedBitrate`.

I read the docs, however, I don't get the difference between these two properties...

Comment: Is this any use to you? http://blog.spooningfork.com/post/44787139787/http-live-streaming-ios-avplayer

observedBitrate - bitratethat the player is seeing / using / reporting / observing.
indicatedBitrate - bitrate that you define in your playlist

Comment: Ok, great. I will add this as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://blog.spooningfork.com/post/44787139787/http-live-streaming-ios-avplayer):

ObservedBitrate is the bitrate that the player is seeing / using / reporting / observing.

IndicatedBitrate is the bitrate that you define in your playlist